# Rename Table not working in Exasol despite user having alter table privileges

Tags: exasolution

I am unable to rename a table in Exasol despite using having Alter Table privilege.

Created a user with Alter Table privilege and tried renaming a test table but it didn't worked.
The error that I receive is : [42500] insufficient privileges for renaming object Test_Table.

rename table DEMO.Test_Mahen to DEMO.Test_Mahen_Updated;

The above command should rename the table but it is not working. Is there any additional privilege that I need to give to the user for renaming tables.
The user has following privileges : 
ALTER ANY TABLE
CREATE ANY TABLE
DELETE ANY TABLE
DROP ANY TABLE
EXECUTE ANY FUNCTION
EXECUTE ANY SCRIPT
UPDATE ANY TABLE 
USE ANY CONNECTION

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new role and change schema owner to this role. After that you may grant this role to users who should be able to update \ rename tables in this schema.

All operations within schema should be permitted with this technique, including renaming.